# Intellij single class compilation does not reflect .java file state

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am currently working on a maven project with unconventional structure on Intellij Idea 12 versioned on Perforce.

Main sources directory is `src` in module root instead of `src/main/java`. Same for test sources located in a `tests` directory in module root instead of `src/test/java`.

Whenever I make a `maven clean compile` or use `Build->Rebuildproject` menu, all my changes are reflected. But if I try to use "single class compilation" (`Build->Compile` or `Build->Make Project` menu) or "Make" before running a unit test for example, when I decompile the .class product of that compilation, it never reflects the last changes I made but the last `maven clean compile` or `Build->Rebuildproject` compilation product.

I even tried to delete compiled classes before launching single class compilation but it was still the same behaviour. Plus when I launch "single class compilation", it copies the .java files being compiled in module's target directory.

Compiling the whole project whenever I make a change takes too long to be considered as a viable alternative.

How can I get my changed classes compiled? Any help would really be appreciated.

EDIT : I decompiled my compiled unit test class, and it has differences with the version in source directory. I also checked the classpath when I launch the unit test and both `MODULE_PATH/target/test-classes` and `MODULE_PATH/target/classes` are part of it. So unit tests are launched with compiled classes in target.

Comment: Are your classes loaded from the compiled jar? Then compiling a single class in IDEA will never work.

Comment: Using `Build->Make project` produced the same result. I also tried to run a unit test I was changing with `-verbose:class` option to understand where did he pick the class. But it failed to display it (exact message Class not found: "XXX") as it was part of no jar.

Comment: It seems like I don't understand your setup. Running a unit test in IDEA basically always works especially outside of Maven. I think you set up does not reflect you expectations. If you want IDEA to compile just one class but your application depends on a JAR in the class path (local repository), then, you'd have to repackage the JAR after the single class was compiled. The result basically has to be the same.

Comment: I only changed the unit test class. So when I launch it from the IDE, I expect that what is run is the changed unit test. But it is not the case. What is launched is a previous version. For example I try to add some logs but new logs are not displayed and when I put a break point on the log line and try to step into the code it brings me to an assertion. I checked the launch command and my classpath contains `MODULE_PATH/target/test-classes` and `MODULE_PATH/target/classes`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"unconventional structure" - I'm betting that's your problem.

It's impossible to tell without seeing your project, but I can assume you that IntelliJ IDEA 12 and 13 both behaved as expected.  Your assumptions aren't being met; check your assumptions.

Leave Maven out of it and set up IntelliJ without it.

Comment: What would you like to see about the project which could give you a little more information ?

Comment: I'dn be looking that the project configuration.  I would suggest that you give it a look, because I'm not going to have much time for this today.

Comment: I finally invalidate the cache, delete project settings and reimported the project as maven project and finally, it worked. I don't know what was going on and cannot reproduce.
There remains a weird behavior as some java resources are still copied in `target` directory when project is built.